# Encrypt / decrypt data in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I need to store sensitive data in SQL server and need this encrypting.  This ideally needs encryping and descrypting within SQL server and not in the code of the application(s).  The reason being, the application to add the data to the database will be written by someone else in ASP and I will be pulling out this data and using this within my application which is written in PHP and will therefore need this decryping.

MySQL has a nice little function AES_ENCRYPT but I cannot find anythign similar for MSSQL and I am very unfamiliar with MSSQL, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this one [Introduction to SQL Server Encryption and Symmetric Key Encryption Tutorial with Script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)

Answer (score 1):

> Summary: With the introduction of transparent data encryption (TDE) in
>   SQL Server 2008, users now have the choice between cell-level
>   encryption as in SQL Server 2005, full database-level encryption by
>   using TDE, or the file-level encryption options provided by Windows.
>   TDE is the optimal choice for bulk encryption to meet regulatory
>   compliance or corporate data security standards. TDE works at the file
>   level, which is similar to two Windows® features: the Encrypting File
>   System (EFS) and BitLocker™ Drive Encryption, the new volume-level
>   encryption introduced in Windows Vista®, both of which also encrypt
>   data on the hard drive. TDE does not replace cell-level encryption,
>   EFS, or BitLocker. This white paper compares TDE with these other
>   encryption methods for application developers and database
>   administrators. While this is not a technical, in-depth review of TDE,
>   technical implementations are explored and a familiarity with concepts
>   such as virtual log files and the buffer pool are assumed. The user is
>   assumed to be familiar with cell-level encryption and cryptography in
>   general. Implementing database encryption is covered, but not the
>   rationale for encrypting a database.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> Security has become extremely important in today’s fiercely completive
>   business environment. Industry standards require you to implement firm
>   techniques to secure your data. In SQL Server 2005, security has
>   improved for authentication, authorization, and encryption. Encryption
>   is so much improved that it is almost a new feature in SQL Server
>   2005.
>
> Encryption is the last barrier against a hacker. Technically,
>   authentication and authorization methods should be strong enough to
>   stop hackers before they can view data. But if they do get through,
>   the last trump card for system designers is data encryption. You will
>   not encrypt you all of your data, only very important data like
>   passwords, credit card number, etc.
>
> In the days of SQL Server 2000, you had two options: find third party
>   tools to handle data encryption, if available, or use the built-in
>   encryption, which was very limited.  and [this](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/encryption-2005-1/) might help

[Reference](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/encryption-2005-1/)

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon a great read on SQL Server Cryptographic features. It describes utilizing Transparent Data Encryption (TDE), Encrypted backup feature (introduced in SQL Server 2014), Symmetric and Asymmetric encryption, and Hashing.

All these features differ in implementation, and I strongly suggest reading this article to find out what solution is the best for your needs: http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-confidential-part-ii-sql-server-cryptographic-features/